# PayPal JS working in Sandbox, but not in live

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to implement PayPal JS which has a black Debit or Credit Card button. The problem I am facing is that it is working in the Sandbox environment but after I use the LIVE keys, it does not work. Is there any configuration that I am missing?

SandBox keys: < script data-namespace="paypal" src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<client_id>&currency=USD&components=buttons,hosted-fields,funding-eligibility">

Live keys: < script data-namespace="paypal" src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<client_id>&currency=USD&components=buttons,hosted-fields,funding-eligibility">

[image: PayPal Buttons]

This is the code I am using

```
var FUNDING_SOURCES = [
        paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL,
        paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT,
        paypal.FUNDING.CARD,
    ]

    // Loop over each funding source
    FUNDING_SOURCES.forEach(function (fundingSource) {
        // Initialize the buttons
        var button = paypal.Buttons({
            fundingSource: fundingSource,
            createOrder: function (data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                    shipping_type: 'PICKUP',
                    purchase_units: [{
                        description: "description of an order",
                        amount: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: "2.50",
                        },
                    }],
                    application_context: {
                        shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
                    }
                });
            },
            style: {
                shape: 'rect',
                label: 'pay',
                size: 'responsive',
                branding: true
            },
            onApprove: function (data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                    alert("Paid");
                });
            },
            onCancel(data) {
                debugger
                console.log(data);
                // Show a cancel page, or return to cart
            },
            onError(err) {
                debugger
                // For example, redirect to a specific error page
                //window.location.href = "/your-error-page-here";
                console.log(err);
                alert(err);
            }
        })
        // Check if the button is eligible
        if (button.isEligible()) {
            // Render the standalone button for that funding source
            button.render('#paypal_buttons')
        }
    });
```

Comment: actions.order.create and actions.order.capture are deprecated and should not be used for any new integration. See the standard checkout integration guide for an example using backend (server) routes,  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/

Comment: @PrestonPHX Thanks, I will add the backend logic for these 2 methods. Do you know why it is still not working with LIVE keys but works fine with SANDBOX keys?

Comment: No since this question has no errors, no diagnostic information, and no problem description besides "it's not working"